# Travis Build Multiple Docker Images from a Single Repo

Tags: git, travis-ci

I'm trying to build Docker for multiple architectures. My repo is here:

https://github.com/mastermindg/docker-flow-proxy

I've created two Dockerfiles (amd64 and armv7). I've included the additional code into the .travis.yml.

**How do I build both Docker images with a single travis yaml?**

Comment: Make a [Build matrix](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build#Build-Matrix)

Comment: Does Travis install each variant in the build matrix? The builds are slightly different so I'd need environmental variables. Can I add these in the build matrix?

Comment: Maybe, depends. Yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a build matrix to build:

```
env:
  global:
    - VERSION=1.${TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER}
  matrix:
    - ARCH=x86_64
      GOIMG=golang:1.6
      DOCKER_BUILD=mastermindg/docker-flow-proxy:${VERSION}
      DOCKERFILE=Dockerfile.amd64
    - ARCH=rpi
      GOIMG=kutsudock/rpi-alpine-go
      DOCKER_BUILD=mastermindg/docker-flow-proxy:rpi-${VERSION}
      DOCKERFILE=Dockerfile.rpi

sudo: required

services:
  - docker
.................
```